# Yellow warning when referencing another project in an azure webjob

Tags: azure, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, azure-webjobs

I have a WebAPI running on Azure WebApps developed with EF Code First.

Now I need WebJobs for some scheduling tasks which should refer to the same DB and Models.

I tried adding reference of the WebAPI project but that marks the DLL as yellow exclamation.

I'm unable to get how should I proceed. Can you please guide me a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Frederico suggests, you should split your Web API project into multiple projects.

If you isolate the **Data Access Layer** (EF Context + query) into a separated assembly, it will be easier for you to share the database access into several projects. Moreover you will not have to add reference to web specific dll (for example `System.Web.Mvc` or `System.Web.Razor`) into your webjob project.

Anyway you have some yellow warning because your Web API and you Azure web job don't target the same .Net framework.

Right-click on your project then select properties. you should be able to adjust the .Net Target framework.

To be able to reference a project A into project B, the project A should target a .Net framework with a version less or equals than the targeting .Net framework of the project B
[image: Choose .Net target framework into Visual Studio Project]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I know that I did it wrong and I should have spitted my WebAPI and Business Logic / DAL Layer. I'll try to refactor the same gradually. But the first issue I'm encountering is that, ASP.NET Identity. As I'm using ASP.NET Identity with EF, how should I proceed? I'm asking this because, ASP.NET Identity generates API's automatically. Also I notice that it doesn't maintain the inter tables (i.e. AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles etc.) under ApplicationDbContext. But still I can refer it as User / ApplicationUser. But if I seperate the DAL project, I don't get context's User / ApplicationUser

Comment: @KrishnanduSarkar, can you rename the title of your post ? This is not a problem about azure or webjob. Something like that : yellow warning when referencing another project in an azure webjob ?

Comment: Done :) So can you please help about my question on if I separate by DAL layer how I'm going to implement ASP.NET Identity?

Comment: I think you should create a new question with your code that need to be isolated. Add a link to the new question so that we can have a look

Comment: Sure. I'll do that. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your EF DbContext class and entities resides inside your Web API project. This monolithic approach brings many problems in integration scenarios like the one you shown.

My advice is to modularize your solution and move all your Data Access related classes (DbContext, entities) inside another project which will be referenced by both your Web API and WebJobs projects.

This is a common approach for improving the maintainability of the code and enforce basic software engineering principles like separation of concerns, and is obtained by dividing your application into different functional layers (a.k.a. multi-layered architecture).

If you are interested you can read more about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396